# Making a Server User ID function | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get all user's ID and name from a server which I done so by using this:

```
const list = client.guilds.cache.get("GUILD_ID"); 
list.members.cache.forEach(member => console.log('Name: ' + member.user.username + ' ID:     ' + member.user.id));
```

But i want to input those member ID's and names into a .json file and I tried doing this via a function:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token  = 'TOKEN';
const prefix = 'a';

const getuser = require('./GetUserId/getID.json');
const fs = require('fs');
const { readdirSync } = require("fs");
const { join } = require("path");

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = readdirSync(join(__dirname, "GetUserId")).filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(join(__dirname, "GetUserId", `${file}`));
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('message', message => {
if (message.content === 'getID'){
  getuser(message);
  function getuser (message) {
    const list = client.guilds.cache.get("749337851174322288"); 
    if(!getuser[message.author.id]){
      getuser[message.author.id] = {
        ID: `${list.members.cache.forEach(member => member.user.id)}`,
        Name: `${list.members.cache.forEach(member => member.user.username)}`
      }
    }
    fs.writeFile('./GetUserId/getID.json', JSON.stringify(getuser, null, 2), (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err)
    })
  }
  message.delete()
  message.channel.send(`*Done.*`)
  }
})

client.login(token);
```

So I tried this code and this came on the .json file:

```
{
  "709827684888215582": {
    "ID": "undefined",
    "Name": "undefined"
  }
}
```

**How would I make the "ID" display user ID's and display all members username in "Name:" in a server/guild in that .json file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), not [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

`forEach()` simply executes a function on all elements of an array (or a Collection, in this case). `map()` creates a *new* array populated with the results of the function.

[image]

Comment: But how would I put those names in the "./getID.json" file?

Comment: [This is how it will appear in your `JSON` file](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/722174152357707776/761630765917143070/unknown.png)

Comment: Where do i put that code? In the function or anywhere? I'm sorry im quite new to this